# How does the RSA private key passphrase work under the hood?

Tags: security, encryption, rsa

RSA private keys may be assigned a "passphrase" which - as I understand it - is intended to provide some secondary security in case someone makes off with the private key file.

How is the passphrase layer of security implemented?

Comment: RSA itself does no such thing. It sounds like you're talking about some particular program that uses RSA -- in which case it would be extremely helpful if you were to tell us what program you're talking about (e.g. PGP or GPG).

Comment: Interesting - mostly I'm curious about the passphrase requested by running "ssh-keygen -t rsa" on unix-y systems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

ssh-keygen uses OpenSSL to generate RSA keys and store it in PEM format. The encryption you are talking about is specific to PEM. If you look at your key file,

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,5B01E932988DC66B

EPESt4ZVIrxnQXxxWWVa7cCR+vgNZ/4vTu4mdq6pjaW7jMZoB8HV+mA745mQkQw7
i+YtdVs/JqOeyGiw/3McxYYKZTlhyh7MvfIr1n8ZdZmcjQz+oFqMxChFU3r8BGgA
```

"DEK-Info" header has all the information you need to decrypt the key as long as you know the passphrase. "DES-EDE3-CBC" means Triple DES (in EDE mode). CBC is the chaining mode. The hex number is the initial vector needed for CBC.

PEM is a very old format so it only supports DES/TripleDES. AES and Blowfish were added later on but not supported by all implementations. My ssh (OpenSSH 5.2) only supports DES and TripleDES.

Comment: @Phaedrus see https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/c0d5ac5e62a6531f640bdfb4897a9fe95a0c9fdb/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/ParserTest.java#L412

Comment: This answer seems to be missing on how to translate password to decryption key accepted by the cipher.

Comment: what does that integer 4 represent in Proc-Type?

Answer (score 42):

The passphrase is just a key used to encrypt the file that contains the RSA key, using a symmetric cipher (usually DES or 3DES). In order to use the key for public-key encryption, you first need to decrypt its file using the decryption key. ssh does this automatically by asking your for the passphrase.

If somebody got a hold of the key's file, they wouldn't be able to use it unless they knew the passphrase used to encrypt the file.

Comment: Thanks much for the reply! Couple of follow-on questions: Is the passphrase part of the RSA standard or something else (as per the commenter above)? Does the ssh-keygen program use DES or 3DES / how would I tell? What grade? Why not AES?

Answer (score 12):

Private keys stored on general-purpose file systems (as opposed to tamperproof, special-purpose hardware tokens) could be easily stolen if not protected. File system permissions might seem sufficient, but they can often be bypassed, especially if an attacker has physical access to the machine.

A strong symmetric cipher, keyed with a good password, helps prevent this. A good RSA private key is too long to remember (for me, anyway), but far smaller symmetric keys can provide the same level of security. A relatively short, symmetric key stored in one's brain is used to protect a large private key stored on disk.

Comment: Definitely makes sense -- any more details as to how, exactly, it's implemented? (Which symmetric exactly, whether that's standard for all impls, etc?)