# Aren't private keys vulnerable in memory?

Tags: security, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to understand what happens when I use a password-protected private key to generate a message digest.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774469/how-does-the-rsa-private-key-passphrase-work-under-the-hood/1774538#1774538) that password-protected private keys are just encrypted using a password-based symmetric key.

Once I enter the correct password, how is a digest generated without exposing the unprotected private key?

Comment: It's exposed in RAM yes. (Unless you're using special crypto hardware such as a TPM)

Comment: @CodeInChaos: so what's the point of encrypting it? Is it really *that* much harder to locate it in memory than on disk?

Comment: Surely the actual key will at some point have to be in memory somewhere. The big question is how long will it be there and who else has potentially got access to it. Freezing a computer with liquid nitrogen can keep the memory content intact for a considerable amount of time, and forcing a swap-to-disk is another problem. Good crypto programs should take care to overwrite the memory content as promptly as feasible.

Comment: @Kerrek, if you convert your comment into an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point the cryptographic primitives in your code *will* need to access and use the actual value of the key. There's simply no way around that. In a simple analogy, you cannot compute `a + b` if you don't know `a`.

The big question concerning secure software design thus boils down to how long sensitive information will persist in an unprotected state. Any sort of password caching is your enemy here, but even if neither the password nor the decrypted key are explicitly cached, they're still in memory at some point. Freezing a computer with liquid nitrogen can keep the memory content intact for a considerable amount of time, and forcing a swap-to-disk is another problem.

Good cryptographic programs should take care to overwrite the memory content as promptly as feasible and minimize the amount of time that sensitive information is retained in readable form. This requires careful analysis of which information is critical (e.g. the user's password input), and platform-specific knowledge of memory management (e.g. can you request non-pageable memory?).

It all depends on your threat model - which sort of attack do you need to protect against? If a rootkit monitors all your memory, you might be in trouble, though that rootkit would probably just read the user's password entry from the keyboard anyway.

This is a complicated issue, and there's extensive research into secure hardware design. In general, the more access an attacker has to your machine, the more likely it is that she'll be able to read sensitive data. Good design can only strive to minimize the surface of attack.

Comment: Hardware cryptographic modules are common. Some are expensive (thousands of dollars), some are extremely cheap (one dollar).  They protect the key so that "your code" can never access it.

Answer (score 2):

At some point the key has to be available in memory for use by the crypto algorithm.

There have been interesting attacks to try and grab valuable information from memory.  One I read about involved plugging a device into a Firewire controller and using direct memory access to poke around for interesting things.

http://www.hermann-uwe.de/blog/physical-memory-attacks-via-firewire-dma-part-1-overview-and-mitigation

It's entirely possible that either a program with necessary privilege to read the memory location holding the key, or hardware utilizing DMA, can grab a private key from RAM.

Comment: Additionally, there's the Cold Boot attack. Turns out that RAM doesn't degrade as quickly as one might usually think is does. So if you leave your computer unattended,(or it's stolen) someone can extract the private key from it.

http://citp.princeton.edu/pub/coldboot.pdf
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cold_boot_attack

Comment: If the person that downvoted this happens back, please explain your downvote.  Nobody learns from an anonymous downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Generally yes, once decrypted the key will be stored in system memory as cleartext until the application or operating system marks it's address as re-writable.  With PGP Desktop, it's possible to manually clear the cached private key, a nice feature I wish more applications offered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is exposed in RAM, and unless the operating system supports protection of memory against paging, and the application uses that feature, the private key can be paged to disk "in the clear." Development tools and active attacks can look for it in memory.

This is one reason specialized hardware cryptographic modules exist. These perform operations with the private key in their tamper-proof memory space; the application can never access the private key itself, it delegates cryptographic operations to the device.