# Is it acceptable to store a GPG'd 4096-bit RSA SSH private key in public?

Tags: security, encryption, ssh, ssh-keys, gnupg

Consider the situation where you have an SSH key pair that you wish to back up.

Choice A: Store the id_rsa file in QR code form on a piece of paper in a safe.

Choice B: Use GPG (symmetric) to encrypt the id_rsa file using a 31 character random mixed case alphanumeric password, put the password in QR code form on a piece of paper in a safe and then leave the id_rsa.gpg file in plain sight for anyone to see. (This has the advantage that the QR code needs to store far fewer bytes and can be printed more compactly). The encryption command used for Choice B would be:

```
gpg -c --force-mdc --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count 65011712 --output id_rsa.gpg id_rsa
```

Is Choice B an acceptable practice? If not, would changing the password to be longer than 31 characters make it acceptable? If it is acceptable, is there a way of describing how much of a risk is being taken by going for Choice B? Assume the SSH key itself has an empty passphrase. Thanks!

(edit: as pointed out in the comments, the desire to store the id_rsa.gpg file publicly is to ensure that lots of copies can be stored in lots of places so that we don't worry about losing a copy of it and don't worry about every single one of those storage locations being secure)

(edit 2: It also occurred to me that if Choice B is satisfactory, Choice B would be a good way to store not only SSH key pairs but regular asymmetric GPG key pairs too).

Comment: If you do that, better keep multiple copies of that keystore file, because it can no longer be recovered from the piece of paper alone (in case of hard disk crash).

Comment: Also, why does the SSH key have an empty passphrase? Isn't your scheme exactly equivalent to protecting it with a passphrase? Why not just use that function?

Comment: Thanks, yes that's exactly the reason to store the ir_rsa.pub and the id_rsa.gpg in a large number of public places, so that the piece of paper would be enough to recover the SSH key pair.

Comment: OTOH, losing an SSH key is not that terrible a problem. You can always generate and install a new one (provided you still have some way to access the server, and that way could be inconvenient as you rarely need it). I'd rather create three different keys than have three backups (that way, you can revoke them individually).

Comment: My understanding is that if I used a 31 char random mixed case alphanumeric passphrase on the SSH key directly, that'd be massively easier to brute force than if I used the same password via GPG, due to the large number of salted iterations used to generate the GPG key from the password, which is superior to the way that SSH passphrases are used.

Comment: Okay, now you have a proper question: "Is GPG passphrase encryption superior to SSH key passphrase protection for the same passphrase?"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774469/how-does-the-rsa-private-key-passphrase-work-under-the-hood (seems to enforce your point, only DES and 3DES in ssh, no AES for example)

Comment: Okay, re-read the question. More important part is "Should I store the encrypted key in public view?" (presumably because it makes for more reliable storage options -- which I have to doubt in the presence of readily available Dropbox or Gmail or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

If using a new enough version of OpenSSH (>=6.5) it's possible to generate private keys using a new private key format (uses bcrypt as the password based key derivation function). This would alleviate concerns over brute-forcing the passphrase and make using a passphrase-protected key an equivalent (and simpler) option to choice B.

Note that this only affects the private key, which means the public key can still be used in older SSH server versions.

See for here for more details:
http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/new-openssh-key-format-and-bcrypt-pbkdf

If the concern is backing up the key pair to guarantee availability, you only need to worry about backing up the private key as the public key can always be derived from it.

Whether the approach is acceptable or not depends on what is the tradeoff you want to make in terms of security vs availability. 
e.g. having a 30+ character passphrase/gpg-protected key will not help if there is a key-logger on any of the systems where the key is used that is able to capture the passphrase. It is generally recommended to keep private keys stored only on the location where they are generated.
A more secure approach would be to use a smart-card/usb token on which the private key is generated and used from.

Comment: Thank you, that answer is useful. I'm still trying to ascertain the key point though, which is: If I use a new private key format with a better KDF, is that KDF secure enough that I can publicly disclose the passphrased private key without worrying about the passphrase being brute forced.

Comment: @AndrewParks No, you should not disclose a private key.  John the Ripper already has the capability to crack both new and old SSH key formats, with not only pure brute force, but also much smarter attacks as well as rule-based dictionary attacks.  The attacks will also only get better over time.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords Thanks for your comment. I understand why it would be foolish to disclose a private key with a memorable passphrase. However, if a password generator is used that generates a securely random mixed case alphanumeric password (call it 6 bits per character), then a 43 character passphrase would essentially constitute a 256 bit symmetric key, which is the surely the gold standard in symmetric key lengths? If I can't disclose my passphrased private key, then aren't you effectively telling me that a 256-bit symmetric key is not secure enough?